# Get number of characters per line of contenteditable div where the caret is on

Tags: jquery, html

im making a text editor for my site so im using contenteditable div.I need to get number of characters of line when i place my caret on that line.Here is my div

```
<div class="article" contentEditable=true ></div>
```

i ve tried this code of jquery

```
$('.article').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
var len = $('.article').text().length;
$('#output').val(len);
});
```

but this gives the whole number of characters in the div.I want to get the number of characters of the line where my caret would be on and output the result in any textarea say

```
<div class="article" contentEditable=true >
 line1
 <div>line--2</div>
 <div>line---3</div>
 </div>

<textarea id="output"></textArea>
```

so if I place my caret on line1 , textarea get '5' in it in real time and if I place my caret on line3 i.e., line---3 , textarea gets = 8 in it in real time.Can you help figure out how to do this?

Comment: look at selectionStart and selectionEnd http://jsfiddle.net/5vd8pxct/

Comment: but how can i judge from selection start and selection end if a line has any characters in it or not so that i can do anything with that particular line?